# How to count when a link is clicked?

Tags: java, jsp, web

My webpage have number of links referring to other sites.  On every click of the link I have to count that this particular link was clicked from my site.

How can I do this? I am using JSP as view technology with tomcat as web Server.

Comment: Generally, you have all of your links pointing to an internal count process, and the internal count process actually links to the external sites.

Comment: This answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/5862803/1862502

Comment: actually what I was thinking that I should make all Linkes like  http://{mywebsite}/{aServletForCounter}?referedWeb=referingwebsiteUrl   By doing this way I can count which link was clicked. and after counting click redirect to the refereed url. . Is my approach  right ?

Comment: @NirbhayMishra your approach sounds good. Else you could have a javascript that fires a ajax request to your counting servlet along with the url. After firing the ajax request you could let the normal link click flow through

Comment: where are you trying to save the counts on server side or in client side ?

Comment: server side . .I have to save this count in logs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google analytics it is easy to setup javascript to record the clicks.  This would be far easier than setting up your own redirection as you can still use actual url anchors instead of urls that go through your server.

Answer (score 0):

google analytics has something called event tracking

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide