# count clicks for each specific link

Tags: javascript, click-counting

I have a page of distinct links. I'm trying to create a JavaScript counter that counts how many times each individual link has been clicked.

I can count general clicks on any `<a href>` element. How can I count clicks on each individual link?

So,

> 1. Bookmark #1 - Cracked.com - Clicked 3 times
> 2. Bookmark #2 - Collegehumor.com - Clicked 1 times
> 3. etc...

```js
var clickcounts = '0';

function count() {
  clickcounts++;
  alert(clickcounts);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:count();">count clicks</a>
```

Comment: Just added the requested code.

Comment: Call a count function with ´this´ as parameter ´javascript:count(this);´ like that you got a reference to the element clicked.

Comment: Just saw your response, mins. However, what if there is a ton of links? Any performance issues from your method?

Comment: I cannot say. Seems to be the usual method for this (e.g. explained [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?48698-What-is-the-best-way-to-count-clicks-on-links).) Possible duplicate of: [How to count clicks with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862781/how-to-count-clicks-with-javascript?lq=1)

Comment: If the user wipes the cache it might mess up the counter.

Comment: If you want to persist the counters further than the current document display, you need to use cookies or database.

Comment: If I use PHP without a web server could it write to a flat file instead?