# Count Accordion Clicks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

Here is the situation, I have accordions and I like to count each time that the user opens the accordion.

How is it possible to have that feature implemented.

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count clicks with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862781/how-to-count-clicks-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you call an accordion but it doesn't really matter; In your script part, you can simply add a function :

```
var count = 0;
function eventCount() {
    this.count++;
}
```

and simply use the hover(`onmouseover="eventCount()"`) or the click(`onclick="eventCount()"`) events on your accordion, depending what you want.

example on a button:

```
<button onclick="eventCount()">Click me</button>
```

then, by calling the variable `count` in your javascript, you'll know how many times the user clicked/hovered the accordion

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.